# Add and retrieve to mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am building a small php application where you can add people and then see them on a page. When I was simply adding it went fine, but then I started using a switch and now it doesn't work to either add or retrieve. I cannot see any problem in my syntax, can anyone see something wrong?

php

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("hostWasHere","username","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("dbIsHere", $con);

try{

    switch($_POST['action'])
    {
        case 'retrieve':
            $show=mysql_query("Select * from test",$con);

     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($show)){
        echo "<li><b>$row[firstName]</b> : $row[lastName]</li>";
     }
        mysql_close($con);
            break;

        case 'new':
            $sql="INSERT INTO test (firstName, lastName)
VALUES
('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);
            break;
    }

}




?>
```

The javascript using this is :

```
function saveToServer() {
alert("clicked");
$.post("api.php", {
        'action': "new",
        'fname': $('#fname').val(),
        'lname': $('#lname').val()
    },
    function () {
        alert("succes");
    }
);

}

function getFromServer() {
  console.log("in get!");
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "api.php",
    data: "action=retrieve",
    success: function (data) {
        $("#comment").html(data);
        console.log("success!");
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: What happens when 'it doesn't work' ? Any error displayed ?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` - Plus, your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: Indent the code, it often reveals obvious errors. Don't use mysql_* since it's deprecated and won't be supported in the future. Use prepared statements, someone (anyone) could drop your database after only 1 minute research of how to. Are there any bugs in your developer tools?

Comment: `data: "action=retrieve",` in your ajax call should be `data: {'action':'retrieve'},`. And if you add a default case to switch, you will get the answer :)

Comment: I will use mysqli and prepared statements, thanks for the tip, I also added the error reporting and I get nothing. Also added case default to echo "skipped to default" and I don t get that either. It does make the request to php because I see in the network of developer tools and no I have no bugs in the developer tools. I also modified the data : action=retrieve thing, thanks Think Different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `try` block without any `catch` or `finally` – this doesn't work. Most likely, your server is configured not to output any errors, so it dies silently.

A few other remarks:

- As pointed out in the comments, please use PDO or MySQLi instead of the deprecated MySQL class.
- Beware of SQL injection and always sanitize properly, no excuses. (My code below with PDO uses `prepare` and takes care of this.)
- Use quotes when you're accessing an array with a string as key: `$_POST['fName']` or `$row["lName"]`, as opposed to `$row[lName]`.
- Output *all* errors while you're developing your page by adding `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the top of your file. Note that server settings may still suppress the error output, but this generally takes care of everything.
- Using a `switch` statement with a lot of code is never a good idea; you want to keep all code there rather lightweight or switch to a combination of `if`, `else if` and `else`.

---

*Enough talk*. Here's my edit for your page, using PDO instead of the deprecated MySQL family.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// PDO has more options to read about
// for initialization, but this should do for now
$con = new PDO("host=host;dbname=db_here", "username", "password");

if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: !');
}

// Do some validation on $_POST before using it.
$action = '';
if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
}

if($action == 'retrieve') {
    $sql = $con->execute('SELECT * FROM test');
    $rows = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($rows as $row) {
        echo '<li><b>'.$row['firstName'].'</b> : '.$row['lastName'].'</li>';
    }
    $con = null;
}
else if($action == 'new') {
    $sql = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO test (firstName, lastName)
                            VALUES (?, ?)');

    // TODO: more checks on fname and lname before accepting
    if(isset($_POST['fname']) || isset($_POST['lname'])) {
        $result = $sql->execute( array($_POST['fname'], $_POST['lname']) );
        if(!$result) {
            die('Error occured');
        }
        else {
            echo 'Added 1 row';
        }
    }

    $con = null;
}
else {
    // TODO: Default page
}
```

---

PS: Please don't ever trust user input. The code is still inserting `$_POST` values rather blindly (just checking that they're at least set), further checks with `is_scalar()` and some length checks would probably be good.

I hope this can help – good luck with your project!

Comment: thank you so much, not only is this a great example but all of your notes are of huge help to me. I agree with every point you made, as for the large amount of code in the switch, I was eventually going to make a class with it's own methods and just call them there. For the user input, I'll do all the checks in the frontend I think, but again, great tips